# No visible @interface for 'DDExpression' declares the selector 'evaluateWithSubstitutions:error:' error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ddmathparser

I have an array which I want to validate: **{"2","+","3","=","5"}**

So how would I do it? I found DDMathParser and theoretically I would be able to validate my expression like so:

```
NSString *expression = [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];


NSError *error = nil;
DDExpression *e = [DDExpression expressionFromString:expression error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"parsed: %@", e);
    NSNumber * result = [e evaluateWithSubstitutions:expression error:&error];
    //error: No visible @interface for 'DDExpression' declares the selector 'evaluateWithSubstitutions:error:' 
}
```

Any thoughts why? I must mention this method is inside my singleton but when I moved it to my view controller error stayed.

Comment: Have you added `DDExpression.m` to your target? Have imported the `DDExpression.h` or just using a forward class declaration (`@class`)?

Comment: @MikeD: I used #import "DDMathParser.h"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [this project](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/tree/master/DDMathParser) (GiHub link), I did not see a method `evaluateWithSubstitutions:error:`.

From the GitHub project, it looks like the full method signature is ([source](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/blob/master/DDMathParser/DDExpression.h), line 33):

```
- (NSNumber *) evaluateWithSubstitutions:(NSDictionary *)substitutions evaluator:(DDMathEvaluator *)evaluator error:(NSError **)error;
```